# node.js server.js module'simple debug' error

Tags: node.js

I am fairly new at node.js, I am using the most recent node.js available .12 on windows 8.1 OS. I am tring to run a program that controls some robotics using a gesture control device, but whenever I run the node server.js I receive the following:

module.js:338 
      throw error
module cannot be found 'simple debug'

I ran npm install simple debug to see if the modules didn't install correctly with original node.js. There are two modules simple and debug and they are installed. I tried the faye install and express solutions and got nothing.

Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Can you post your package.json file?  Are you sure you've spelled the names correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using [this module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-debug), you should consider adding the hyphen for `simple-debug` instead of `simple debug`.